# Coherence - Cookie Session Sharing between Applications Hosted on Different Servers

Tags: cookies, dns, virtualhost, proxy-server

Coherence - Cookie Session Sharing between Applications Hosted on Different Servers

i have some **web application** on different servers i need them to have shared cookie 
session in browser.

i want to assign same domain to all of them with different urls.
how can i implement this?

is it actually gonna work?
i want to do it with virual host on a **proxy** server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way that comes to mind is to create a symbolic link in your DocumentRoot to a mounted directory which exists on another server. If you do this cross-server and for each application, then no matter which server people arrive at (due to load balancing, etc.) each server has a 'complete' set as far as apache is concerned but actually you still have the different data in its respective place.

In your `/html/` directory (example DocumentRoot) you would have:

```
application1/
application2 -> /mnt/application2/
application3 -> /mnt/application3/
```

Then you'd set up the mount - for example - so a `df` would have:

```
192.168.1.2:/var/www/html/application2   ...   /mnt/application2
192.168.1.3:/var/www/html/application3   ...   /mnt/application3
```

Doing it this way keeps the guy on the same site as far as apache and his browser, etc. are concerned and you are definitely using the same domain, but essentially just splitting the file system between servers based on url.